# didFinishLaunchingWithOptions never called on ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios7

When launching on ios6 the app is correctly launched but on ios7 there is just black screen without any error or warning in console. I put a breakpoint in main.m and it seems that is never called on ios7. Here my device console logs on ios7 (unsuccesfull launch):

```
>         Oct 23 14:02:28 iPad mobile_installation_proxy[92] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Please include the kCFBundleIdentifierKey in the
> options dictionary when installing an app.
>     Oct 23 14:02:28 iPad mobile_installation_proxy[92] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installing app for existing placeholder (null)
>     Oct 23 14:02:28 iPad installd[60] <Notice>: 0x247000 handle_install_for_ls: Install of
> "/var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/Getsy iPad.app" requested by
> mobile_installation_proxy
>     Oct 23 14:02:28 iPad installd[60] <Notice>: 0x247000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app com.getsyLLC.iPad
>     Oct 23 14:02:29 iPad SpringBoard[33] <Warning>: Killing com.getsyLLC.iPad for termination assertion
>     Oct 23 14:02:29 iPad installd[60] <Notice>: 0x247000 install_application: Performing developer delta patch
>     Oct 23 14:02:29 iPad installd[60] <Notice>: 0x247000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Staging: 0.06s; Waiting: 0.00s;
> Installation: 0.38s; LS Sync: 0.00s; Overall: 0.44s
>     Oct 23 14:02:29 iPad ***[70] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating identifier store
>     Oct 23 14:02:29 iPad syncdefaultsd[195] <Notice>: (Note ) SYDAccount: no account
>     Oct 23 14:02:29 iPad SpringBoard[33] <Error>: libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:837: front-facing-camera cannot generate notifications
> yet
>     Oct 23 14:02:29 iPad SpringBoard[33] <Error>: libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:835: ipad is static and will never generate a
> notification
>     Oct 23 14:02:29 iPad SpringBoard[33] <Error>: libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:835: any-telephony is static and will never generate a
> notification
>     Oct 23 14:02:29 iPad SpringBoard[33] <Error>: libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:835: stand-alone-contacts is static and will never
> generate a notification
>     Oct 23 14:02:29 iPad SpringBoard[33] <Error>: libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:835: still-camera is static and will never generate a
> notification
>     Oct 23 14:02:30 iPad com.apple.debugserver-300.2[197] <Warning>: debugserver-300.2 for armv7.
>     Oct 23 14:02:30 iPad com.apple.debugserver-300.2[197] <Warning>: Connecting to com.apple.debugserver service...
>     Oct 23 14:02:30 iPad com.apple.debugserver-300.2[197] <Warning>: Got a connection, waiting for process information for launching or
> attaching.
>     Oct 23 14:02:36 iPad com.apple.debugserver-300.2[197] <Warning>: About to launch process for bundle ID: com.getsyLLC.iPad
>     Oct 23 14:02:36 iPad kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[198] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/52388E56-13D5-4470-B848-05B807DE72B4
> (sandbox)
>     Oct 23 14:02:36 iPad com.apple.debugserver-300.2[197] <Warning>: In completion handler, got pid for bundle id, pid: 198.
>     Oct 23 14:02:36 iPad com.apple.debugserver-300.2[197] <Warning>: Got a connection, launched process /Developer/usr/bin/debugserver.
>     Oct 23 14:04:39 iPad awdd[200] <Error>: CoreLocation: CLClient is deprecated. Will be obsolete soon.
```

And logs form device ios6 (success launch)

```
Oct 23 15:05:19 iPad-virt mobile_house_arrest[6632] <Error>: Max open files: 78
Oct 23 15:05:20 iPad-virt profiled[6625] <Notice>: (Note ) profiled: Idled.
Oct 23 15:05:20 iPad-virt profiled[6625] <Notice>: (Note ) profiled: Service stopping.
Oct 23 15:05:20 iPad-virt installd[54] <Error>: 0x2ff72000 handle_install: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/Getsy iPad.app" requested by mobile_installation_proxy
Oct 23 15:05:21 iPad-virt installd[54] <Error>: 0x2ff72000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app com.getsyLLC.iPad
Oct 23 15:05:21 iPad-virt installd[54] <Error>: Oct 23 15:05:21  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
Oct 23 15:05:22 iPad-virt SpringBoard[5373] <Warning>: Killing com.getsyLLC.iPad for termination assertion
Oct 23 15:05:23 iPad-virt lsd[85] <Warning>: updating identifier store
Oct 23 15:05:23 iPad-virt lsd[85] <Warning>: Attempting to store identifiers file
Oct 23 15:05:23 iPad-virt installd[54] <Error>: 0x2ff72000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Staging: 0.21s; Waiting: 0.00s; Installation: 1.72s; LS Sync: 0.05s; Overall: 1.98s
Oct 23 15:05:23 iPad-virt mobile_installation_proxy[6636] <Error>: 0x3c4f6b88 MobileInstallationSlowLookupBreak: MobileInstallationBrowse was called without specifying an options dictionary containing kLookupReturnAttributesKey. This usage is inefficient and may cause performance problems. Break on MobileInstallationSlowLookupBreak to debug.
Oct 23 15:05:23 iPad-virt mobile_installation_proxy[6636] <Error>: 0x3c4f6b88 MobileInstallationSlowLookupBreak: Existing options dictionary: <CFBasicHash 0x1fd5be80 [0x3ab85100]>{type = mutable dict, count = 2,
    entries =>
        1 : <CFString 0x4a1a0 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "RequestProxiedFor"} = <CFString 0x1fd5c0a0 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "iPhone Configuration Utility"}
        6 : <CFString 0x1fd5aac0 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "ApplicationType"} = <CFString 0x1fd5c1c0 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "User"}
    }
Oct 23 15:05:23 iPad-virt kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[6634] Builtin profile: syncdefaultsd (sandbox)
Oct 23 15:05:25 iPad-virt installd[54] <Error>: 0x2fef0000 filter_attributes: Info.plist keys requested via MobileInstallationLookup/Browse in client Xcode (via mobile_installation_proxy) were not found in MobileInstallation's cache. Please file a bug requesting that these keys be added: <CFBasicHash 0x1e61edf0 [0x3ab85100]>{type = mutable set, count = 18,
    entries =>
        0 : <CFString 0x3ab719f4 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "CFBundlePackageType"}
        1 : <CFString 0x1e61f6b0 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "BuildMachineOSBuild"}
        2 : <CFString 0x3ab72a44 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "CFBundleResourceSpecification"}
        3 : <CFString 0x1e61f7b0 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "DTPlatformBuild"}
        4 : <CFString 0x3ab6f794 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "DTCompiler"}
        5 : <CFString 0x3ab71564 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "CFBundleSignature"}
        6 : <CFString 0x3ab72224 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "DTSDKName"}
        7 : <CFString 0x1e62cb60 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "NSBundleResolvedPath"}
        8 : <CFString 0x3ab6eeb4 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "UISupportedInterfaceOrientations"}
        10 : <CFString 0x3ab76e84 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "DTXcode"}
        13 : <CFString 0x3ab76eb4 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion"}
        16 : <CFString 0x3ab74304 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "CFBundleSupportedPlatforms"}
        17 : <CFString 0x1e61b370 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "DTXcodeBuild"}
        18 : <CFString 0x1e62cb80 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "UIStatusBarTintParameters"}
        19 : <CFString 0x3ab72e54 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "DTPlatformVersion"}
        20 : <CFString 0x3ab75bf4 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "DTPlatformName"}
        21 : <CFString 0x3ab76c84 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "CFBundleDevelopmentRegion"}
        22 : <CFString 0x1e61b350 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "DTSDKBuild"}
    }
Oct 23 15:05:25 iPad-virt installd[54] <Error>: 0x2ff72000 filter_attributes: Info.plist keys requested via MobileInstallationLookup/Browse in client Xcode (via mobile_installation_proxy) were not found in MobileInstallation's cache. Please file a bug requesting that these keys be added: <CFBasicHash 0x1e534100 [0x3ab85100]>{type = mutable set, count = 18,
    entries =>
        0 : <CFString 0x3ab719f4 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "CFBundlePackageType"}
        1 : <CFString 0x1e629540 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "BuildMachineOSBuild"}
        2 : <CFString 0x3ab72a44 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "CFBundleResourceSpecification"}
        3 : <CFString 0x1e62cc60 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "DTPlatformBuild"}
        4 : <CFString 0x3ab6f794 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "DTCompiler"}
        5 : <CFString 0x3ab71564 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "CFBundleSignature"}
        6 : <CFString 0x3ab72224 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "DTSDKName"}
        7 : <CFString 0x1e61f730 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "NSBundleResolvedPath"}
        8 : <CFString 0x3ab6eeb4 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "UISupportedInterfaceOrientations"}
        10 : <CFString 0x3ab76e84 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "DTXcode"}
        13 : <CFString 0x3ab76eb4 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion"}
        16 : <CFString 0x3ab74304 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "CFBundleSupportedPlatforms"}
        17 : <CFString 0x1e61f6d0 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "DTXcodeBuild"}
        18 : <CFString 0x1e61f780 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "UIStatusBarTintParameters"}
        19 : <CFString 0x3ab72e54 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "DTPlatformVersion"}
        20 : <CFString 0x3ab75bf4 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "DTPlatformName"}
        21 : <CFString 0x3ab76c84 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "CFBundleDevelopmentRegion"}
        22 : <CFString 0x1e61f6b0 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "DTSDKBuild"}
    }
Oct 23 15:05:26 iPad-virt installd[54] <Error>: 0x2ff72000 filter_attributes: Info.plist keys requested via MobileInstallationLookup/Browse in client Xcode (via mobile_installation_proxy) were not found in MobileInstallation's cache. Please file a bug requesting that these keys be added: <CFBasicHash 0x1e528310 [0x3ab85100]>{type = mutable set, count = 18,
    entries =>
        0 : <CFString 0x3ab719f4 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "CFBundlePackageType"}
        1 : <CFString 0x1e52b210 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "BuildMachineOSBuild"}
        2 : <CFString 0x3ab72a44 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "CFBundleResourceSpecification"}
        3 : <CFString 0x1e52faa0 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "DTPlatformBuild"}
        4 : <CFString 0x3ab6f794 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "DTCompiler"}
        5 : <CFString 0x3ab71564 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "CFBundleSignature"}
        6 : <CFString 0x3ab72224 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "DTSDKName"}
        7 : <CFString 0x1e51c4c0 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "NSBundleResolvedPath"}
        8 : <CFString 0x3ab6eeb4 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "UISupportedInterfaceOrientations"}
        10 : <CFString 0x3ab76e84 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "DTXcode"}
        13 : <CFString 0x3ab76eb4 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion"}
        16 : <CFString 0x3ab74304 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "CFBundleSupportedPlatforms"}
        17 : <CFString 0x1e521240 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "DTXcodeBuild"}
        18 : <CFString 0x1e523f30 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "UIStatusBarTintParameters"}
        19 : <CFString 0x3ab72e54 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "DTPlatformVersion"}
        20 : <CFString 0x3ab75bf4 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "DTPlatformName"}
        21 : <CFString 0x3ab76c84 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "CFBundleDevelopmentRegion"}
        22 : <CFString 0x1e529650 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "DTSDKBuild"}
    }
Oct 23 15:05:26 iPad-virt installd[54] <Error>: 0x2ff72000 filter_attributes: Info.plist keys requested via MobileInstallationLookup/Browse in client Xcode (via mobile_installation_proxy) were not found in MobileInstallation's cache. Please file a bug requesting that these keys be added: <CFBasicHash 0x1e61edf0 [0x3ab85100]>{type = mutable set, count = 18,
    entries =>
        0 : <CFString 0x3ab719f4 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "CFBundlePackageType"}
        1 : <CFString 0x1e61b2c0 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "BuildMachineOSBuild"}
        2 : <CFString 0x3ab72a44 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "CFBundleResourceSpecification"}
        3 : <CFString 0x1e61b3c0 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "DTPlatformBuild"}
        4 : <CFString 0x3ab6f794 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "DTCompiler"}
        5 : <CFString 0x3ab71564 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "CFBundleSignature"}
        6 : <CFString 0x3ab72224 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "DTSDKName"}
        7 : <CFString 0x1e61f6b0 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "NSBundleResolvedPath"}
        8 : <CFString 0x3ab6eeb4 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "UISupportedInterfaceOrientations"}
        10 : <CFString 0x3ab76e84 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "DTXcode"}
        13 : <CFString 0x3ab76eb4 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion"}
        16 : <CFString 0x3ab74304 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "CFBundleSupportedPlatforms"}
        17 : <CFString 0x1e62cc10 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "DTXcodeBuild"}
        18 : <CFString 0x1e61f6d0 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "UIStatusBarTintParameters"}
        19 : <CFString 0x3ab72e54 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "DTPlatformVersion"}
        20 : <CFString 0x3ab75bf4 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "DTPlatformName"}
        21 : <CFString 0x3ab76c84 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "CFBundleDevelopmentRegion"}
        22 : <CFString 0x1e62cbf0 [0x3ab85100]>{contents = "DTSDKBuild"}
    }
Oct 23 15:05:26 iPad-virt mobile_house_arrest[6641] <Error>: Max open files: 78
Oct 23 15:05:26 iPad-virt mobile_house_arrest[6642] <Error>: Max open files: 78
Oct 23 15:05:27 iPad-virt com.apple.debugserver-199[6644] <Warning>: debugserver-199 for armv7.
Oct 23 15:05:27 iPad-virt kernel[0] <Debug>: lockbot[6630] Builtin profile: debugserver (sandbox)
Oct 23 15:05:27 iPad-virt com.apple.debugserver-199[6644] <Warning>: Connecting to com.apple.debugserver service...
Oct 23 15:05:27 iPad-virt com.apple.debugserver-199[6644] <Warning>: Got a connection, waiting for process information for launching or attaching.
Oct 23 15:05:27 iPad-virt mobile_house_arrest[6645] <Error>: Max open files: 78
Oct 23 15:05:27 iPad-virt mobile_house_arrest[6646] <Error>: Max open files: 78
Oct 23 15:05:27 iPad-virt mobile_house_arrest[6647] <Error>: Max open files: 78
Oct 23 15:05:27 iPad-virt mobile_house_arrest[6648] <Error>: Max open files: 78
Oct 23 15:05:27 iPad-virt mobile_house_arrest[6649] <Error>: Max open files: 78
Oct 23 15:05:27 iPad-virt mobile_house_arrest[6650] <Error>: Max open files: 78
Oct 23 15:05:27 iPad-virt mobile_house_arrest[6651] <Error>: Max open files: 78
Oct 23 15:05:27 iPad-virt mobile_house_arrest[6652] <Error>: Max open files: 78
Oct 23 15:05:27 iPad-virt mobile_house_arrest[6653] <Error>: Max open files: 78
Oct 23 15:05:27 iPad-virt mobile_house_arrest[6654] <Error>: Max open files: 78
Oct 23 15:05:27 iPad-virt mobile_house_arrest[6655] <Error>: Max open files: 78
Oct 23 15:05:27 iPad-virt mobile_house_arrest[6656] <Error>: Max open files: 78
Oct 23 15:05:28 iPad-virt mobile_house_arrest[6657] <Error>: Max open files: 78
Oct 23 15:05:28 iPad-virt mobile_house_arrest[6658] <Error>: Max open files: 78
Oct 23 15:05:28 iPad-virt mobile_house_arrest[6659] <Error>: Max open files: 78
Oct 23 15:05:28 iPad-virt mobile_house_arrest[6660] <Error>: Max open files: 78
Oct 23 15:05:28 iPad-virt mobile_house_arrest[6661] <Error>: Max open files: 78
Oct 23 15:05:28 iPad-virt mobile_house_arrest[6662] <Error>: Max open files: 78
Oct 23 15:05:28 iPad-virt mobile_house_arrest[6663] <Error>: Max open files: 78
Oct 23 15:05:28 iPad-virt mobile_house_arrest[6664] <Error>: Max open files: 78
Oct 23 15:05:28 iPad-virt mobile_house_arrest[6665] <Error>: Max open files: 78
Oct 23 15:05:28 iPad-virt mobile_house_arrest[6666] <Error>: Max open files: 78
Oct 23 15:05:28 iPad-virt mobile_house_arrest[6667] <Error>: Max open files: 78
Oct 23 15:05:28 iPad-virt mobile_house_arrest[6668] <Error>: Max open files: 78
Oct 23 15:05:28 iPad-virt mobile_house_arrest[6669] <Error>: Max open files: 78
Oct 23 15:05:30 iPad-virt lockdownd[45] <Notice>: 01523000 store_escrow_record: Creating escrow bag (hash=1d94eb449e7e98d588baaab9dfcb90a83c9ad0e5) for 2C0C933A-8E46-4D85-8F1E-00BD652E3501
Oct 23 15:05:32 iPad-virt mobile_house_arrest[6670] <Error>: Max open files: 78
Oct 23 15:05:32 iPad-virt mobile_house_arrest[6671] <Error>: Max open files: 78
Oct 23 15:05:32 iPad-virt mobile_house_arrest[6672] <Error>: Max open files: 78
Oct 23 15:05:35 iPad-virt backboardd[5372] <Notice>: Posting 'com.apple.iokit.hid.displayStatus' notifyState=1
Oct 23 15:05:35 iPad-virt kernel[0] <Debug>: set_crc_notification_state 0
Oct 23 15:05:35 iPad-virt backboardd[5372] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: detection mode: 255->0 (deferring until bootloaded)
Oct 23 15:05:35 iPad-virt profiled[6673] <Notice>: (Note ) profiled: Service starting...
Oct 23 15:05:35 iPad-virt profiled[6673] <Notice>: (Note ) profiled: Recomputing passcode requirement message
Oct 23 15:05:35 iPad-virt com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.getsyLLC.iPad[0x6ac4][6675]) <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.getsyLLC.iPad[0x6ac4]) Spawned and waiting for the debugger to attach before continuing...
Oct 23 15:05:35 iPad-virt backboardd[5372] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: device bootloaded
Oct 23 15:05:35 iPad-virt backboardd[5372] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: detection mode: 0->0
Oct 23 15:05:35 iPad-virt kernel[0] <Debug>: ALS: AppleARMBacklight::handleMessageGated - framebufferState -> 1
Oct 23 15:05:35 iPad-virt kernel[0] <Debug>: ALS: AppleARMBacklight::setBacklightEnableGated 1 (set level to 0x516)
Oct 23 15:05:35 iPad-virt amfid[6676] <Error>: Oct 23 15:05:35  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
Oct 23 15:05:36 iPad-virt com.apple.debugserver-199[6644] <Warning>: Got a connection, waiting for debugger instructions.
Oct 23 15:05:36 iPad-virt kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[6675] Builtin profile: container (sandbox)
Oct 23 15:05:36 iPad-virt kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[6675] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/90A821AD-8C8A-4A72-9ACC-C0FF019AC76D (sandbox)
```

Comment: Try resetting the ios7 simulator and quit it and then again Run application

Comment: I've tried in both simulator and iPad(tried with 2 different ipads with ios7). Resetting content, reinstalling app - still same result for ios7- main.m never called, app not crashed. Just black splash screen when launching app.

Comment: any fix for this? we have the same issue.